# how to print .sh files in linux

Tags: javascript, angular, linux, shell, command-line

Here I'm printing the Linux command and echoing the result

```
 cpu_info() {
  local lscpuCommand=$(type -P lscpu)    
  result=$($lscpuCommand \
   $AWK -F: '{print "\""$1"\": \""$2"\"," }  '\
  )
 $ECHO "{" ${result%?} "}" | _parseAndPrint
}
```

above peace of code is getting result same way I'm trying to print below code, but I'm not getting result
,if I print direct in cli **lsof -i :8085** it give the output, I want to execute in below code

```
portRunning_processes() {
  result=$(lsof -i :8085)
  $ECHO "[" ${result%?} "]" | _parseAndPrint
}
```

[image: the is output Im gettting when I print lsof -i :8085 , same way I want in portRunning_processes function]

Comment: Sorry but its not that much clear, could you please do add more information in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh .I have attached the image, the output I'm getting like command = node and Pid = 84290,  I wan to print in same way in **portRunning_processes()** function, their I'm unable to print, what is getting wrong I dont know that, for eg you can check with **cpu_info()**